# How can I retrieve this schema by SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table and its data :

```
-------------------------------------
rid  mid  qty   price  tname
-------------------------------------
10   A    1000  400    Buy
11   A    2000  420    Buy
12   B    1700  600    Buy
13   A    600   450    Sell
```

And I want to have such output :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
mid   SUM_Buy  tname  SUM_Sell  tname  SUM_Buy_minus_SUM_Sell
----------------------------------------------------------------
A     3000     Buy    600       Sell    2400
B     1700     Buy    NULL      NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Please, no images. Use formatted text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for updating your question with consumable data. An even better approach is posting ddl and sample data so people can just grab it and roll. I did that for you.

```
declare @something table
(
    rid int
    , mid char(1)
    , qty int
    , price int
    , tname varchar(10)
)

insert @something values
(10, 'A', 1000, 400, 'Buy')
, (11, 'A', 2000, 420, 'Buy')
, (12, 'B', 1700, 600, 'Buy')
, (13, 'A', 600 , 450, 'Sell')
```

In that type of format it is super easy for others to help.

You can solve this using conditional aggregation. I used tname1 and tname2 because outside of SSMS you don't want multiple columns to have the same name. But those are probably just noise and not really needed as they provide no benefit to the results.

```
select s.mid
    , Sum_Buy = sum(case when tname = 'Buy' then qty end) 
    , tname1 = 'Buy'
    , Sum_Sell = sum(case when tname = 'Sell' then qty end) 
    , tname2 = 'Sell'
    , SUM_Buy_minus_SUM_Sell = sum(case when tname = 'Buy' then qty end) - sum(case when tname = 'Sell' then qty end)
from @something s
group by s.mid
order by s.mid
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try [***this***](http://rextester.com/YDU12258) ( use *grouping by* `mid` column with aggregations by contribution of `case..when` statements ) :

```
with t(rid,mid,qty,price,tname) as
(
select 10,'A',1000,400,'Buy' union all
select 11,'A',2000,420,'Buy' union all
select 12,'B',1700,600,'Buy' union all
select 13,'A',600,450,'Sell'    
)
select t.mid, sum(case when tname='Buy' then qty else 0 end) as SUM_Buy,
       min(case when tname='Buy' then tname else null end) as tname,
       sum(case when tname='Sell' then qty else null end) as SUM_Sell,
       max(case when tname='Sell' then tname else null end) as tname,
       (sum(case when tname='Buy' then qty else 0 end) -
         sum(case when tname='Sell' then qty else null end)) as 
       SUM_Buy_minus_SUM_Sell
  from t
 group by t.mid
```